# sourceTree in the latest version of win10 does not start

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, cordova-win10

my OS system is the latest version of win10 Pro ,
SourceTree is also the latest version i downloaded from the official site.

when i installed it, a icon came out.Then i double click the icon,SourceTree  had no response.

Before i asked this question, i had tried to reinstall it many times.Unfortunately,it was not work for me.

it had troubled me for a week , is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall sourcetree and then reinstall it. Usually works for me when I have issues like that on my computer.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version ???
Before i asked this question, i had tried this way many times.Unfortunately,it was not work for me.